# Renewing DHCP lease without losing static IPs? (dhclient removes static IPs)

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhclient

I have this interface, with DHCP and some static IPs:

```
$ ip addr
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d5:5e:13:19:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.208/24 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.88.87/24 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.15/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e2d5:5eff:fe13:19d9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

e.g. 192.168.88.87

When I lose the Internet, I try to get it back with this command:

```
sudo dhclient -r enp3s0 && sudo dhclient enp3s0
```

However, this removes all my static IPs from the interface:

```
$ ip addr
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d5:5e:13:19:d9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.208/24 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::e2d5:5eff:fe13:19d9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any ideas how to renew the DHCP lease without deleting my static IPs?

Comment: You should not be mixing DHCP and Static on a single interface, it leads to problems like this.  If you must have a static AND a DHCP, you should be using a second interface for the DHCP one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly edit the /etc/network/interfaces file and create sub-interfaces.

In that case, you would have something like:

```
auto enp3s0 inet dhcp

auto enp3s0:0
iface enp3s0:0 inet static
        address 192.168.88.8
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your router/gateway, and see if you can reserve your static IP addresses from the assigned DHCP range.  On a Linksys router, the main screen has a "Connectivity" screen, and on that screen, there is a "DHCP Reservations" button.  Fill in your static addresses, with MAC, and they will be preserved, and not otherwise assigned.

Answer (score -1):

This is the problem with mixing DHCP and Static on the same interface.

**You should either do all-static or all DHCP**, and not mix on the same interface.

Failing that, you could do something such as this:

```
sudo dhclient -r enp3s0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.88.87/24 dev enp3s0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.15/24 dev enp3s0
```

However, if you *choose* to do this we also need to know the proper *routes* here, such as for the 192.168.88 address - what gateway IP does it use, etc.

Also note that with this type of setup in play, you *may* run into networking NOT working properly anymore because the routing will be totally messed up.  **This is why I suggest ONLY using Static or DHCP, not both.**

Alternatively, use a second Ethernet adapter and then use *that* one for DHCP and the other for Static.  This would solve the problem easily.

Comment: That does not answer my question :( - I need to mix static and DHCP on 1 interface, this is a requirement of this installation. There is no default gateway on the static IPs, these are IP cameras where the manufacturer chose to put them on a different subnet. This is working just fine, with the exception of dhclient removing my static IPs.

Comment: @RomanGaufman *actually* it does, I **give you the answer** right in the middle of that with my "you could do something such as this" - if you WANT to use static AFTER a DHCP call you have to manually add the static IPs and their corresponding route(s) back in.  That's unfortunately the only way to really do this in networking.  Waht's really happening however is your IP routes are being deleted, which can be fixed if you properly configure the static IPs and the routes rather than using DHCP routes.  (The DHCP part that gets your internet back is only the default route being set...)